# Show that sublevel set $C$ is convex if $A \succcurlyeq 0$

Tags: convex-analysis

> Let $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be the solution set of a quadratic inequality,
>
> $$ C = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x^TAx + b^Tx + c \le 0 \}$$
>
> with $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $C$ is convex if $A \succcurlyeq 0$

How does one prove it for the general case? I would think we would need to use the general definition of convexity somehow: if $\theta x_1 + (1-\theta)x_2 \in C$ where $\theta \in [0,1]$ and $x_1,x_2 \in C$ then $C$ is convex. But I don't know how to apply this.

Comment: Are you sure you did not mean $A \ge 0$? Take $n=1, A=-1, b=0, c=1$ to see that $C$ is not convex with $A \le 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, thank you.

Comment: The function $f(x) = x^TAx+b^Tx+c$ is convex, hence the level sets are convex.

Comment: @copper.hat I agree that once we know it is convex, the level sets are convex. But I am not sure how to prove $x^TAx + b^Tx + c$ is convex.

Comment: $x \mapsto b^Tx$ is linear, hence convex. The Hessian of $x \mapsto x^TAx$ is $A$ which is psd hence convex. The sum of convex functions is convex.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you! That was a big help.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathrm A \succeq \mathrm O_n$, then there exists an $n \times r$ matrix $\rm Q$ such that $\rm A = Q Q^\top$, where $r = \mbox{rank} (\rm A)$. Hence,

$$\mathrm x^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm x + \mathrm b^\top \mathrm x + c = \mathrm x^\top \mathrm Q \mathrm Q^\top \mathrm x + \mathrm b^\top \mathrm x + c \leq 0$$

Using the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement), the quadratic inequality above can be rewritten as the following [linear matrix inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_matrix_inequality) (LMI)

$$\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm I_r & \mathrm Q^\top \mathrm x \\ \mathrm x^{\top} \mathrm Q & - c - \mathrm b^{\top} \mathrm x\end{bmatrix} \succeq \mathrm O_{r+1}$$

whose solution set is a [spectrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrahedron) and, thus, convex.

---

[convex-analysis](/questions/tagged/convex-analysis) [schur-complement](/questions/tagged/schur-complement) [linear-matrix-inequality](/questions/tagged/linear-matrix-inequality) [spectrahedra](/questions/tagged/spectrahedra)