# $\{x^TQx \leq \alpha\}$ is convex when $Q$ is SPD

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, quadratic-forms, positive-definite

> Suppose $Q^T = Q \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ and $x^T Q x \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$. Show the set $$S = \{ x \in \mathbb R^n \mid x^T Q x \leq \alpha\}$$ where $\alpha > 0$ is given, is convex.

My attempt:

Let $x,y \in S$. We want to show that $tx + (1-t)y \in S$ where $t \in [0, 1]$

If we show $\langle Q(tx + (1-t)y), tx + (1-t)y\rangle \leq \alpha $ we are done.

Simplying this, we get

$t^2\langle Qx, x \rangle + (1-t)^2\langle Qy, y\rangle + 2t(1-t)\langle Qx,y \rangle \leq t^2\alpha+(1-t)^2\alpha + 2t(1-t)\langle Qx,y\rangle$

Now, we can define $f(t) = \alpha t^2 + \alpha (1-t)^2$, where $t \in [0, 1]$, $\alpha > 0$. It is very easy to check that the maximum of this function is actually $\alpha$. So we can simplify even further, and say

$t^2\alpha+(1-t)^2\alpha + 2t(1-t)\langle Qx,y\rangle \leq \alpha + 2t(1-t)\langle Qx, y\rangle$

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: You are asking for a proof that the epigraph of a convex function is convex?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3366875/339790

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: use the fact that
$$
2\langle Qx,y\rangle\le\langle Qx,x\rangle+\langle Qy,y\rangle.
$$

Comment: Why is this true? I don't know this inequality I think.

Comment: @OriaGruber It is the same as $\langle Q(x-y),x-y\rangle\ge 0$ that comes from PSD.

Comment: Thanks! I always miss the obvious things...

Comment: @OriaGruber It is not very obvious, I am just aware of this trick from my class in Optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an easier approach is to write $Q=L^TL$ for some $L\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ by PSDness, so your set is just $\{x:\|Lx\|_2^2\leq \alpha\}=\{x:\|Lx\|_2\leq \sqrt{\alpha}\}$. Can you show this set is convex for any $\alpha$?